# How to know if excel file has macros using python?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlrd, vba

HI I am new managing excel files, I would like to know if there is any variable in xlutils, xlrd, xlm, etc libraries that give true or false in case Macros are activated or now? Is there any way to know it from metadata before open? Wat is the best approach for know it?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: The suffix `.xlsm` must be used for files with macros in them.

Answer (score 0):

It's technically *possible* but very unlikely that Excel is calling any Python functions.

A quick [Google Search](https://www.google.ca/search?num=100&dcr=0&q=use%20python%20with%20vba) shows lots of people asking if VBA can use Python, and a few theoretical responses, but nothing solid.

What I would do to confirm, is move all the "mystery python scripts" to another folder.  If someone complains that things suddenly don't work any more, then move them back.

If a couple months pass and everything's still working properly, it's unlikely that anyone *needs* them.

---

**Edit**:

*Figures...* as I was writing that answer someone posted [a VBA/Python question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49225410/8112776)!

...but out of curiousity, I queried [SE Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?order_by=featured):

[`Questions`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?order_by=featured) `with tags like %vba% or %excel%:                212,299`

[`Questions`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?order_by=featured) `with tags like %python% and (%vba% or %excel%):   5,808    (2.7%)`